# Execute class method from ZK button in grid

Tags: java, button, grid, zk

Need help with this.

**Post.java** is an object that has an User who posted it, a String of info and an Int with the number of likes. **PostData.java** saves a list of all the posts in an ArrayList. **PostViewModel.java** communicates with the zul.

The zul:

```
<zk>
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('fb.PostViewModel')">
<grid height="550px" model="@load(vm.postData.posts)" emptyMessage="Nothing in Posts.">
<template name="model">
<row>
<window border="normal">
<caption label="@load(each.user.getNombre())"/> 
<label value="@load(each.info)" />
<separator bar="true"/>
<button label="Like" onClick="addLike()"/>.
<textbox id="likeTB" disabled="true" value="@load(each.likes)" width="30px;"/>
<zscript>
public void addLike(){
//Somehow add to the object Post's likes one.
//Temporary fix that just modifies the textbox.
//String test = likeTB.getValue();
//Integer num = Integer.parseInt(test);
//num++;
//likeTB.setValue(num+"");
}
</zscript></window></row></template></grid></window>
</zk>
```

My question is, how can I, using the Like button, go to the object Post where I gave Like and use the method addOneLike()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume your post has an `id` or some other way of being unique. I'm also going to assume that your zscript code will be moved to a view model. You can do the following in your zul code:

```
<button label="Like" onClick="@command('addLike', id=each.id)"/>
```

And then in your view model:

```
@Command
public void addLike(@BindingParam("id") long id) {
    // post with id like++
}
```

Comment: Your posts must be stored in a database(?) I would use the unique id from the table row.

Comment: Thanks to you, i now have given each post an id given by their hashcode. An error happened while i tried using your onClick solution, so i modified it. The window of each post has its ID set by the (each.id), so each window has the id of the post in it.
My new question is, how can i make the button, when pressed, to ask for the window its in for its id? Using "this" doesnt work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited my answer above; note changes in both zul and view model

Comment: Thanks a lot, col!